Problems knowing what structs to use to work with undirected graphs
I have a project in C that requires me to manipulate an undirected graph. My main question is about the structures that I will be using. So far this is what I've got from my teacher's explanations:
struct Node {
    char name[MAX_CHAR];            // stores the node name
    struct Edge *connections;       // stores all of the edges connected to said node??
};

struct Edge {
    struct Node destination;        // stores the destination node??
    int days;                       // edge weight
};

struct Graph {
    struct Node *nodes;             // stores all of the nodes on the graph
    int num_nodes;                  // number of nodes in the graph
};

I am not very certain of what 'struct Edge *connections' and 'struct Node destination;' do and how I'm going to implement them on a function like create_graph or add_edge. Is there a better way to work with undirected graphs?
I just want to make sure I start with the right foot on this project and not struggle afterwards with the structs I implemented
I've seen some youtube videos about it and some forums, but they are mainly doing directed graphs and working with linked lists from what i understand

struct Edge *connections; is most likely meant to be an array of edges; remember that in C, "arrays decay to pointers". However, when passing an array like this in c, you need to have some way of determining the size of the array or at least to have some dummy element at the end of the array that marks its end.

You are entirely correct that this choice of structure seems appropriate for a directed graph. In fact, in computing, graphs are almost always represented as directed graphs, there is no real way around that. You just need to make sure, when you implement your functions that manipulate these structures, that for every edge A->B, there is always the corresponding edge B->A. In other words, your conceptually "undirected graph" is represented as a directed graph in which we enforce the constraint that every directed edge has a corresponding reverse-direction directed edge.

To be honest, I think this structure is pretty bad unless you know the whole graph in advance. For instance, if you want to call add_edge(struct Node *from, struct Node *to, int days) to add an edge between nodes from and to, you're going to need to reallocate both arrays from->edges and to->edges to make room for the extra edge.

So you would be better-off either using linked lists rather than arrays, as you've suggested, or implementing a struct DynamicArray first and then using that.
